# Apache superset authorization logging

Tags: python, apache-superset

To be safe, we want to monitor user authorizations in apache superset.

Example from documentation https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/event-logging/
does not allow to see the ip address of the user and the result of authorization.

> {"action": "DashboardRestApi.info", "json": {"path":
> "/api/v1/dashboard/_info", "q": "(keys:!(permissions))", "rison":
> {"keys": ["permissions"]}}, "dashboard_id": null, "slice_id": 0,
> "duration_ms": 41, "referrer": "/superset/welcome/", "user_id": "3"

Are there other ways to monitor users in superset?

Comment: did u solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom logger class that extends `DBEventLogger` to add additional details to your events or log any custom messages you may need.

Ref: https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/event-logging/